# How to display file only downloadable by a specific user based on username/student number?

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I'm still a beginner with this so I hope you understand. I've been working to create a simple student portal for our college this pandemic times.

I will make a student portal so the students specially graduated students can see their own admin-uploaded softcopy documents, like good moral, grade slips/cards, and other certifications and soon they can see their grades. I completed the front end, register, login and out process, but I'm having a hard time to code in uploading the files/documents in the site.

1. What can I do to upload the files for a specific student number?
2. Can I match the student's number to the filename to be uploaded? E.G. Student Num.=123456789; filename: 123456789.pdf

More Example (Scenario):

Student No. 1234568789 wants to download the files, he/she will register first, then login, and in the homepage, directly (i will not create downloads page), the documents specifically for him/her will be displayed and be available to download.

Comment: Why not have a table which records which document belongs to which student?

Answer (score 0):

If you just upload the documents to a directory following some kind of structure and serve them as static files, your system will be vulnerable to students guessing other students' file path and downloading them.

I think ideally you'd create a database table (`attachments` or whatever) associated to the students table to store the documents path (which is inaccessible statically, if it were to be accessed directly your webserver would return `403 Unauthorized`), then use PHP to retrieve and serve the document if the student is authorized to see it (if it's associated to the student record on the database).

Something like:

```php
$currentStudentId = 10; // This would come from the login session
$documentId = 73; // This could come as a URL param

// Fetch the attachment associated to the student from the DB
$query = 'SELECT filepath FROM attachments WHERE student_id = ? AND id = ?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $currentStudentId, $documentId); // Be sure to read about prepared statements if you're using mysqli
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_row();
$attachment = $row[0];

if (!$attachment) {
  // Return a 404 if the attachment doesn't exists or it's not associated to this student
  http_response_code(404);
  die('Attachment not foud');
} else {
  // Read and serve the file
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
  readfile("{$attachment['filepath']}.pdf");
}
```

Of course when the file is uploaded, you'd need to create the `attachments` record in the DB correctly associated to the `student_id` and with the correct `filepath`. The actual filename can be random, it doesn't matter, as long as it doesn't conflicts with other files, it's not accessible statically, and it's correctly saved in the `attachments` table.